# Why don't sessions start properly in Internet Explorer and Google Chrome, but work fine in Firefox?

Tags: php, google-chrome, internet-explorer, session, firefox

I'm asking (and answering) this question mainly because I couldn't find anything that exactly matched my specific circumstance in any of the other similar SO questions asked, nor did any of them that I read exactly match the solution I found. It's my hope that this will benefit others in the future.

I'm trying to set a very restrictive session cookie that is valid only for the admin section of my site, so I'm using session_set_cookie_params() to do so. Here is the original code:

```
  // Set session parameters
  $session_name = 'PGO_Admin';
  $session_lifetime = 86400; // 24 hours, expressed in seconds
  $session_cookie_path = './'; // This session is only valid within the confines of the admin folder
  $session_cookie_domain = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER,'HTTP_HOST');
  session_set_cookie_params($session_lifetime, $session_cookie_path, $session_cookie_domain);
  session_name($session_name);
  session_start();
```

This code works well in Firefox, but fails in IE and Chrome. In Firefox, if I put in some PHP code to display the contents of $_SESSION, I get this:

```
<!-- SESSION vars:
Array
(
    [GitHubVersion] => 2.4.5
    [poadmin] => Array
        (
            [curPage] => main
            [uid] => 1
            [name] => Dave
            [lip] => 127.0.0.1
            [prior_login] => Tuesday 9th of December 2014 03:11:56 PM
            [ip] => 127.0.0.1
            [last_login] => Tuesday 9th of December 2014 03:42:51 PM
            [bot_id] => 1
            [bot_name] => Test
            [logged_in] => 1
        )
)
-->
```

Which is what I expect to see. In IE or Chrome, however, the same code only produces an empty array:

```
<!-- SESSION vars:
Array
(
)
-->
```

If I comment out the call to session_set_cookie_params(), the script functions properly, but the cookie that gets set is accessible everywhere within the site, and that is not acceptable to me. After banging my head against the wall for several hours, I finally found a solution that's pretty simple. Please see my answer for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my theory:

It seems that Firefox "understands" that './' means the current directory path, while IE and Chrome do not. They expect a "full path" from the server's document root, which in my case was "/Program-O-master/admin/". Armed with this knowledge, I revised the code in the following manner:

```
  $session_name = 'PGO_Admin';
  $session_lifetime = 86400; // 24 hours, expressed in seconds
  $session_cookie_domain = 'http://' . filter_input(INPUT_SERVER,'HTTP_HOST');
  $session_cookie_path = str_replace($session_cookie_domain, '', _ADMIN_URL_);
  /* The constant _ADMIN_URL_ is set earlier, in a different file */
  session_set_cookie_params($session_lifetime, $session_cookie_path, $session_cookie_domain);
  session_name($session_name);
  session_start();
```

This set the "proper" cookie path, and now all of the browsers I've tested with (including several that weren't mentioned earlier) work as expected. I hope this will help others in the future.